# Passing data from a component to the parent viewmodel in Vue.js 2.x

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm just starting with Vue.js and I'm puzzled as of how complicated it is to pass data from a component to the parent viewmodel/component.

My usecase is as follows:

I have a custom rangeslider component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-range-slider). I use 3 of these in a wrapping component `Typetest.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="typetest">
    <div :class="'slider1-val-' + slider1RoundedValue">
      <range-slider
        class="slider"
        min="1"
        max="3"
        step="0.01"
        v-model="sliderValue1">
      </range-slider>
    </div>
    <div :class="'slider2-val-' + slider2RoundedValue">
      <range-slider
        class="slider"
        min="1"
        max="3"
        step="0.01"
        v-model="sliderValue2">
      </range-slider>
    </div>
    <div :class="'slider3-val-' + slider3RoundedValue">
      <range-slider
        class="slider"
        min="1"
        max="3"
        step="0.01"
        v-model="sliderValue3">
      </range-slider>
      <p>{{ slider3Texts[slider3RoundedValue] }}</p>
    </div>
    <p>Your Choice: {{ sliderSum }}</p>
    <!-- this value needs to be passed to the parent viewmodel whenever it changes -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import RangeSlider from 'vue-range-slider'
import 'vue-range-slider/dist/vue-range-slider.css'

export default {
  name: 'typetest',
  data () {
    return {
      sliderValue1: 2,
      sliderValue2: 2,
      sliderValue3: 2,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    slider1RoundedValue: function() {
      return this.calcSliderValue(this.sliderValue1).toString();
    },
    slider2RoundedValue: function() {
      return (this.calcSliderValue(this.sliderValue2)*10).toString();
    },
    slider3RoundedValue: function() {
      return (this.calcSliderValue(this.sliderValue3)*100).toString();
    },
    sliderSum: function() {
      return this.slider1RoundedValue*1 + this.slider2RoundedValue*1 + this.slider3RoundedValue*1
    },
  },
  methods: {
    hello: function() { console.log(this.sliderSum); },
    calcSliderValue: function(val) {
      switch (true) {
        case val < 1.67:
          return 1
          break
        case val < 2.34:
          return 2
          break
        default:
          return 3
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    RangeSlider
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, whenever the computed property `sliderSum` mutates, I need to pass the result to the parent viewmodel. Several other components then need to update according to the parent viewmodel's `sliderSum` property, which at all times needs to be in sync with the component's computed property. It reflects the state of the three range sliders in one value. Depending on this sum I can decide in the parent which texts and images to show.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved it doing the following:

1) I added a data property `sliderSum` on the parent viewmodel,
    initially putting an empty string.

2) I added a method to the parent viewmodel that would update the `sliderSum` property when called, with the argument passed.

```
data() {
  return {
      sliderSum: ""
  }
},
methods: {
  updateSliderValue: function(newVal) {
    this.sliderSum = newVal;
  }
}
```

3) In my parent viewmodel's template, I pass the `updateSliderValue` method to be called whenever an event `sliderValueHasMutated` is emitted:

```
<typetest @sliderValueHasMutated="updateSliderValue"></typetest>
```

4) Inside the `Typetest.vue` component, I changed the (indepent, though identically named) computed property `sliderSum` as follows:

```
sliderSum: function () {
  var sum = this.slider1RoundedValue * 1 + this.slider2RoundedValue * 1 + this.slider3RoundedValue * 1
  this.$emit('sliderValueHasMutated', sum)
  return sum
},
```

So now, whenever the computed property changes, it emits a `sliderValueHasMutated` event that triggers the parent's `updateValue()` method.

Done!